# The glowing effect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In html:
 `<div id="rec_block"></div>`

 In CSS

```
#rec_block{
position: absolute;
top: 340px;
left: 615px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
visibility: hidden; 
}
```

```
var rec_block= $('#rec_block');
rec_block.css('visibility',"visible");
setInterval
(
    function()
    {           
        rec_block.css('background-color',"red");
        rec_block.css('background-color',"green");          
    }           
,1000
);
```

Basically, it will have the glowing effect: change color from red to green and
green to red, but it only changes red to green and nothing happens...

What's wrong with that?

UPDATE: Please explain why the above code can't work...Thanks.

Comment: Your interval is always changing from red to green instantly. So you will never notice a change from green to red. In my answer I used your interval to change the upcoming colour. Then trigger a function that would change the colour. That function will be called every 1000 milliseconds and change the colour to your chosen upcoming colour. Hope my answer helps :).

Comment: @Beneto Thank you, too. Sorry I'm so stupid to ask this question...

Comment: no problem, We've all got to learn :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because color changing happens too fast and you cannot see the terrible(*sorry*), not-user-friendly effect, you can use `setTimeout` function.

```
setInterval(function() {
    rec_block.css('background-color', "red");
    setTimeout(function(){
        rec_block.css('background-color', "green");
    }, 500)
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S8zNX/

An alternative is:

```
setInterval(function() {
    rec_block.css('background-color', function(i, c){
        return c === 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' ? 'green' : 'red'
    });
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9RXw9/

Comment: May I ask how long do the red and green color separately occupies? I got a little confused.

Comment: @Stallman The first example takes 500ms and the second one 1000ms, I  have used `rgb..` as `css` method returns a `rgb` value.

Comment: That's pretty smart method!!

Comment: Wait... What's the argument "i" for?

Comment: @Stallman `css` method accepts two parameters, the first one is _index_ of selected element in jQuery collection, second one is the value of the css property, in this case background-color. you can name it whatever you want, I chose _i_ and _c_.

Answer (score 1):

Just one thing to add to *undefined's* correct answer, you can add this to your css style sheet in order to make this effect a bit smoother.

```
#rec_block
{
     -webkit-transition: background 1000ms linear;
     -moz-transition: background 1000ms linear;
     -ms-transition: background 1000ms linear;
     -o-transition: background 1000ms linear;
     transition: background 1000ms linear;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I haven't tested though.

```
var i = 0;
setInertval ( function (){
    if(i === 0){
        color = '#FF0000'; //red
        i=1;
    }
    else{
        color = '#00FF00'; //green
        i=0;
    }
    changeColor(color);
},1000);
function changeColor(color){
    $('#rec_block').animate.({'background' : color},300);
}
```